# Writable nested Django Serializer error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have this issue:

```
    class UserProfiles(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User)
      role_alt = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)

    class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = UserProfiles
        fields = ('role_alt', )

    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      profile = ProfileSerializer()
      class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')
    def create(self, validated_data):
      profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
      user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
      UserProfiles.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)

      return user
```

getting 
Error:
 
        Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 
        `profile` on serializer `UserSerializer`.The serializer field 
        might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on 
        the `User` instance. Original exception text was: 'User' object 
        has no attribute 'profile'.

Comment: your `validated_data` has no attribute `profile`.  Try this, `profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile','no-profile')`

Comment: Hi Bishnu, you can accept the answer if it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Field names in `ModelSerializer` should be same as field names in model. Default reverse lookup for `OneToOne` field is lower-case model name. Try to rename `profile` to `userprofiles`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  userprofiles = ProfileSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'userprofiles')

  def create(self, validated_data):
     profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofiles')
     user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
     UserProfiles.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)

  return user
```